# What does <Shift-v><Shift-j> do in Vim

Tags: key-bindings

I accidentally discovered that the key combination  will concatenate the current line and the next line. However, I do not recall it being mentioned in the `quickref`. After a quick Google, I did not find anything. Do any have a clue about where in the
documents can I find more about this key combination?

### BTW, I have confirmed that this is not mapped in the `:map`.

**Update**:

With the help from a comment, (Curiously, I saw it in a message. But after I opened the website, it disappeared.) I found that I am actually using the `<shift-j>`, i.e. `<J>` key to join lines. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912905/how-do-i-join-two-lines-in-vi).

**Update 2**:

`J` in visual mode provides extra capabilities. See `:help v_J`. (Thanks to @Antony's comment.)

Comment: Yeah. `J` joins lines,

Comment: See `:help v_J` . Prefix Visual mode commands with `v_` to find them in the documentation. This is explained at `:help`.

Comment: the help command led me to `gJ`, which doesn't add spaces ♥️

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am guessing you were holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key even while pressing `j`. 
Because `V + j` alone would not have concatenated the lines.

`V` is for selecting the entire line.

`j` moves the selection down.

So, this is not the combination that did that for you.

`V + J` on the other hand does exactly that. (holding `shift` for v and j)

`J` here joins the current line to next line (J for Join), which is a default setting in Vim.

You will get the same functionality without having to press `V`. Press `J` in normal mode and it will Join the next line with the current line.

For more info, try `help :join` in Vim.

Comment: As a side note, using `V` to select multiple lines *will* cause a different effect than just doing `J`. It just happens to be the same with only one line.

Comment: What effect are you referring to? The indentation issue?

Comment: `J` with mulltiple lines selected joins all the lines in the selection - it gives you one VERY long line.

Comment: Yeah. That's what it is supposed to do.  `J` joins lines. Plain and simple